# How to turn off the equidistant style on the XSSFTable in Java and use date and time togeter as x-axis?

Tags: java, date, apache-poi

I got this problem:

I have a java function that creates an Excel file.
That file, contains a table, and there I have a timeline.
The row contains dates as strings:

Example: 4.5.2018

As you can see in the picture bellow, I have the date and the time as a string added into the cells.

I created a Scatter Chart, in order to disable the equidistant feature of the line chart.

The problem is, that when I use this chart with just the dates, without the time, all looks fine, like this:

[image: Picture without equidistant feature]

I get the desired equidistant feature turned off, but I loose the points that are at similar time, I loose the points that are equal by the minute

But I need the dates to be together with time, so I change the string to be like this:

Example: 4.5.2018 04:04:28

But then, the chart behaves like a line chart again, with the equidistant feature turned on..

Like this:

[image: Picture with the equidistant feature]

Long story short, I am at the end with my nerves, and i need your help.

For this example, I used for all values 3 and for the dates:

```
26.04.2018 04:04:28 
26.04.2018 04:04:26 
03.05.2018 02:05:39   ... I loose these two
03.05.2018 02:05:56   ...
04.05.2018 10:05:05 
07.05.2018 10:05:40   ... and I loose these two
07.05.2018 10:05:49   ...
```

Here is the code and let me know, if you need some more:

```
    public static byte[] exportData(/*some params*/) {

    ArrayList<Integer> selectedParams = extractParameters(selectedPars);
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();

    // Patient Results
    XSSFSheet sheetResults = workbook.createSheet("Results - PatientID - " + patientId);

    ResteasyClient client = new ResteasyClientBuilder().build();
    ResteasyWebTarget rtarget = client.target(MW_Url + "/rest/mw");
    MWRest rest = rtarget.proxy(MWRest.class);
    List<Result> listOfResults = rest.getResults(scriptId, patientId, startDate, endDate);
    String[][] params = rest.enumerateParams();
    if (listOfResults.size() != 0) {
        final int NUM_OF_ROWS_PR = 3;
        final int NUM_OF_COLUMNS_PR = listOfResults.size();

        Row rowPR;
        Cell cellPR;
        // create the first row
        rowPR = sheetResults.createRow((short) 0);
        for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < NUM_OF_COLUMNS_PR; colIndex++) {
            cellPR = rowPR.createCell((short) colIndex + 1); 
            cellPR.setCellValue(colIndex);
        }

        // create the names of the following 2 rows
        Row rowPR1 = sheetResults.createRow((short) 1);
        cellPR = rowPR1.createCell(0);
        cellPR.setCellValue((String) "Date");

        Row rowPR2 = sheetResults.createRow((short) 2);
        cellPR = rowPR2.createCell(0);
        cellPR.setCellValue((String) "Result");

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("d.M.yyyy h:mm:ss");

        // add data to the 2nd and 3rd row
        for (Result result : listOfResults) {
            cellPR = rowPR1.createCell(listOfResults.indexOf(result) + 1);
            if (result.getExecutionTime() != null) {
                cellPR.setCellValue(sdf.format(new Date(result.getExecutionTime())));
            }

            cellPR = rowPR2.createCell(listOfResults.indexOf(result) + 1);
            if (result.getDoubleValue() != null) {
                cellPR.setCellValue((Double) result.getDoubleValue());
            } else {
                cellPR.setCellValue(0);
            }
        }

        // from here on goes the drawing of the chart
        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        Drawing drawingPatResults = sheetResults.createDrawingPatriarch();
        ClientAnchor anchorPatResults = drawingPatResults.createAnchor(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NUM_OF_ROWS_PR + 1, 29,
                NUM_OF_ROWS_PR + 21);

        Chart chartPatResults = drawingPatResults.createChart(anchorPatResults);

        ScatterChartData dataPatResults = chartPatResults.getChartDataFactory().createScatterChartData();   

        // Use a category axis for the bottom axis.
        ChartAxis bottomAxisPatResults = chartPatResults.getChartAxisFactory()
                .createCategoryAxis(AxisPosition.BOTTOM);
        ValueAxis leftAxisPatResults = chartPatResults.getChartAxisFactory().createValueAxis(AxisPosition.LEFT);
        leftAxisPatResults.setCrosses(AxisCrosses.AUTO_ZERO);

        ChartDataSource<Number> xsPatResults = DataSources.fromNumericCellRange(sheetResults,
                new CellRangeAddress(1, 1, 1, NUM_OF_COLUMNS_PR)); 

        // add the data to the chart to create colored lines
        ScatterChartSeries chartSeriePR = dataPatResults.addSerie(xsPatResults,
                DataSources.fromNumericCellRange(sheetResults, new CellRangeAddress(2, 2, 1, NUM_OF_COLUMNS_PR)));
        chartSeriePR.setTitle("Result");

        chartPatResults.plot(dataPatResults, bottomAxisPatResults, leftAxisPatResults);

        // generate the points(triangles, squares, circles...) on the chart

        XSSFChart xssfChartPatResults = (XSSFChart) chartPatResults;
        CTPlotArea plotAreaPatResults = xssfChartPatResults.getCTChart().getPlotArea();
        CTMarker ctMarkerPatResults = CTMarker.Factory.newInstance();
        ctMarkerPatResults.setSymbol(CTMarkerStyle.Factory.newInstance());


        for (CTScatterSer ser : plotAreaPatResults.getScatterChartArray()[0].getSerArray()) {
            ser.setMarker(ctMarkerPatResults);
        }

    // Prepare for export

        Date today = new Date();
        String strDate = today.toString();
        strDate = strDate.replaceAll(" ", "_");
        strDate = strDate.replaceAll(":", "-");

        String path = userId + "/" + "STARR-DSS_exportData_PatientId-" + patientId + "_ScriptId-" + scriptId + "_"
            + strDate + "_Code-" + today.getTime() + ".xlsx";
        // File file = new File(PATH + path);

        SXSSFWorkbook wb = new SXSSFWorkbook(workbook);

        res.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + path);
        // dispose of temporary files backing this workbook on disk

        try {
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            wb.write(bos);

            return bos.toByteArray();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            wb.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        wb.dispose();

        return null;

    }
```

I can only guess, that it has something to do with the simple date format, but still, I got no idea what to do...

Thank you.

Comment: once I do that, the values in the excel sheet  are not dates, bus some strange numbers like these:43216,66908 43216,67044 43223,59282 43223,59441 43224,44451 43227,44283 43227,44433
In any case, the result is the same as the first case of mine, still I see just 4 points, instead of the desired 6 :(

Comment: Your "strange numbers" are `Excel`'s datetime values. Read the "Busy Developers' Guide" for [how to create date cells](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#CreateDateCells). Furthermore `apache poi` cannot do what `Excel` cannot do. So at first try fulfilling your requirements using `Excel`'s GUI. Then try rebuildung this result using `apache poi`.